# Connect to external Webservice through Azure Web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app that is being deployed to an Azure environment that will need to connect to a third party web service. There are various steps that the third party have confirmed that need to be completed before a connection can be established.

1. Telnet to thier webservice. I know this is not possible through Azure
2. Install a client certifcate supplied from the third party. This has been done.

They have confirmed that the connection should be established at this point. Before deploying the web app how can I check to see if this has been established?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Why can't you just make the webservice call to see if it works? How would you normally test if the app were running locally?

Comment: @chrisblue13 by the way telnet is possible via kudu console. refer http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/azure-web-apps-kudu-console-and-tcpping